# tablayout にてタブ選択時に選択されたタブの背景色をxmlで変えたい

Tags: android

tablayout を　つかって、タブ選択時に選択されたタブの背景色を変えたいと思っております。

xmlをつかってselectorにて state_selectedタグを使って実現しようと思ったのですが
うまく動きません。

シンプルなプログラムだと思うのですが一体何がおかしいのでしょうか。
andrid studioを入れ直してみてもうまく動きませんでした。

かれこれ３日悩んでおります。

どうかご教授ください。

**環境**

- windows10
- android studio 2.3

  - 3.0クリーンインストールでも結果は同じ
  - 実機、シュミレーターでも結果は同じでした

**セレクター**

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_selected="true"　android:drawable="@android:color/holo_red_dark" />
    <item android:drawable="@android:color/holo_purple" />
</selector>
```

**アクティビティメイン.xml**

```
    <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
        android:id="@+id/tab_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="20dp"
        android:background="@drawable/selector_tab"
        app:tabSelectedTextColor="@android:color/holo_orange_dark"
        app:tabTextColor="@android:color/background_dark"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="8dp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="0dp" />
```

**MainAcivity.java**

```
package com.example.user.elementtest;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.design.widget.TabLayout;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        TabLayout tabLayout = (TabLayout)findViewById(R.id.tab_layout);

        tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText("タブ1"));
        tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText("タブ2"));
        tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText("タブ3"));

        tabLayout.getTabAt(0).select();
    }
}
```

**gradle**

target  26
min     23

`compile 'com.android.support:design:26.+'`を追加

**実行結果**

selectorでtrueに指定した背景色にならず、ずっとfalseの背景色になっています。

またこの環境でフォーカス時にボタン変更するようなプログラムも書いてみたのですが
state_forcusも常にfalseでtrueが取れませんでした。

よろしくお願いします。

Comment: selector内のtrueとfalseを入れ替えますと色が入れ替わりますのでセレクターの自体はうまく設定されていると思われます

Comment: マルチポスト　https://detail.chiebukuro.yahoo.co.jp/qa/question_detail/q12181332572

Answer (score 0, accepted):

実際に試していませんが、stackoverflowに同じような[質問](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31640563/how-do-i-change-a-tab-background-color-when-using-tablayout)がありました。
質問にあるコードと見比べたところ、tabの背景色を変更するためには

app:tabBackground

を使うべきなのではないかと思います。
試してみてください~

Comment: qiita にも同じような投稿が
 https://qiita.com/ryohey/items/df96d3f7e56756962380

Comment: Daichi Itokazu　様　見事に解決いたしました。感謝、感激です。android タグばかりに目が言っていまして、まさかapp　タグだとは・・・。たしかにtagBackgroundにて指定することで解決しました。ありがとうございました！

Comment: よかったです~! もしよければベストアンサーをください :) よろしくお願いします。

Comment: すいません。新参なもので、やり方がわからなかったのですが、これでベストアンサーになりましたでしょうか？よろしくお願いします。

Comment: はい、なりました！ありがとうございます :)